# ModuleNotFoundError: importlib when pushing to Heroku despite local changes

Tags: python, django, heroku

I get this error when I try to push to Heroku, the traceback is: `"/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho                                                                                                                                                 n3.7/site-packages/appconf/utils.py", line 5, in import_attribute
2018-12-18T16:39:08.833497+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.utils.importlib import                                                                                                                                                  import_module`

That path doesn't exist on my computer so I assume it's Heroku's own file, but I do have that same file and almost same path in my computer (it's in the directory that's linked to the remote repo. So I went to `utils.py` and commented out the line `django.utils.importlib import                                                                                                                              import_module` and replaced it from `from importlib import import_module` which I've learned is compatible with Python 3.

However I still receive the same error when pushing, because that file isn't updated on Heroku. How would I go about fixing that library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating django-appconf in your `requirements.txt` or pipenv file.

[This change](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-appconf/commit/4848baf76e4972401530b624816ba48cb08d9398#diff-726f27d4685852c611055cc9d513882a), which is included in django-appconf v1.0+, tries to import from `importlib` first, so won't give that error.

Comment: Awesome brother that was exactly it, my django-appconf was set to 0.6. I'm getting a different error now but it's actually running the Django. Cheers!